# Zend Framework Action Helper Problem

Tags: zend-framework, action, helper

I'm a relative noob when it comes to Zend Framework, however I've got a form that I need to use if a couple of views so I thought I might use a Action Helper to instantiate the form set a few attributes and pass it to the relevant view.  I've created the Action Helper and can call it from within the relevant controller's action, however when I try to pass the form to the action's view nothing gets rendered, ie:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Colour;
if($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
{
    $model = new Application_Model_Colour();
    $model->changeColour($form->getValues());  
    $form->reset();
}
else
{
    $form->newColour->setAttrib('disabled', 'disabled');
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or have I got the wrong idea of what an Action Helper can be used for?  Maybe its not an Action helper that I need to use?

Comment: Would you be able to post your view as well, please?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was just being stupid!  Instead of

```
$this->view->form = $form;
```

at the end of the Action Helper I should have done:

```
return $form;
```

Then in my controller:

```
$this->view->form = $this->_helper->myActionHelper->myActionHelperMethod();
```

Silly me...